# Testing for potential discrimination

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

Apologies, I know this is incredibly simple but it's been a while since I was in school!

I'd like to run a significance test on the (dummy) data in the table attached to ascertain whether there has been any discrimination at each stage of the funnel.

[image: Table 1]

i.e. whether more white people are getting accepted than BAME, or vice versa, beyond what is statistically reasonable. I just want to run a quick test for each (offer, approved, confirmed) in excel, but I'm not sure which test I should be using? Chi-Squared, Binomial, standard t?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The approach I was going to take was to calculate the % of total apps for BAME & White applicants, and then apply those %s to the total number of offers to get an expected number for each, before running a chi-squared on those two value vs the observed values in the table above?